# JS accessing data in arrays

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

With a tutorial found on the web I somehow worked out an interactive map out of prepared SVG file.

It shows houses that are free, reserved or sold and it's connected to Advanced Custom Fields in wordpress to change their status (that's why I used [shortcodes]). 
When the house is free it highlights (on hover) green, sold = red, reserved = orange.

Everything is working perfectly but...
I want to create a button that will black out all houses that are sold or reserved leaving only those available.

I will shorten most of the code and show you my attempt of making this work.

First: Array with SVG paths and attributes:

```
 var path = svg.path("M 2163.333,524.667 ... 2169.333,454.667 z");
 path.data('id', 'c1');
 path.data('status', '[statusdc1]');   //////////THIS IS THE DATA I WANT TO GET
 map['c1'] = path;

var path = svg.path("M 2076,546.062 ... 2208.952,618.538 z");
 path.data('id', 'c2');
 path.data('status', '[statusdc2]');   //////////THIS IS THE DATA I WANT TO GET
 map['c2'] = path;
```

Every path has two layers that are shown to the user: path itself and the name (so you may understand what is that index **map[key][0]** and **map[key][1]** later)

```
for (var key in map) {          
    map[key][0].attr({
        'fill': '#fff',
        'opacity' : 0.05,
        'stroke' : '#fff',
        'stroke-width' : 2
    });            

    map[key][1].attr({
        'fill': '#fff',
        'opacity' : 0
        });
}
```

Then there goes the hover effect:

```
map[key].mouseover(function(e) {        
        if (this != activeElement) {

            if(this[0].data('id')=="c1"){
                    if(this[0].data('status')=="sold"){             
                        this[0].animate({
                            'fill': '#c80000',
                            'opacity' : 0.6,
                            'stroke' : '#c80000',
                            'stroke-width' : 2
                        }, 500);
                    }else if(this[0].data('status')=="free"){
                            this[0].animate({
                            'fill': '#A2E22D',
                            'opacity' : 0.6,
                            'stroke' : '#A2E22D',
                            'stroke-width' : 2
                        }, 500);
                    }else{
                            this[0].animate({
                            'fill': '#FFD700',
                            'opacity' : 0.6,
                            'stroke' : '#FFD700',
                            'stroke-width' : 2
                        }, 500);                        
                    }
                    $( ttc1 ).css( "opacity", 1 ); 
            }else if(this[0].data('id')=="c2"){
                    $( ttc2 ).css( "opacity", 1 ); 
                    if(testc2=="sold"){             
                        this[0].animate({
                            'fill': '#c80000',
                            'opacity' : 0.6,
                            'stroke' : '#c80000',
                            'stroke-width' : 2
                        }, 500);
                    }else if(testc2=="free"){
                            this[0].animate({
                            'fill': '#A2E22D',
                            'opacity' : 0.6,
                            'stroke' : '#A2E22D',
                            'stroke-width' : 2
                        }, 500);
                    }else{
                            this[0].animate({
                            'fill': '#FFD700',
                            'opacity' : 0.6,
                            'stroke' : '#FFD700',
                            'stroke-width' : 2
                        }, 500);                        
                    }
```

The code continues for every house. (I know it could be done without so many repeats but that's not the problem here. Everything is working.
Now the problem:

I see how things work when you work on single (hovered over) object by calling to its parameters by THIS selector.

How can I get to those parameters (status) in a for loop going through an array of every house // map[key] ?
Here's my try.

```
var btnstatus=2;

        document.getElementById("btn-check").onclick = function() {checkAvailable()};

    function checkAvailable() {

for (var key in map) {   
            if (btnstatus % 2 != 0){
                if(map[key].data('status')!=="free"){   
                    map[key][0].animate({
                        'fill': '#fff',
                        'opacity' : 0.05
                    }, 500);
                }
            }else{
                if(map[key].data('status')!=="free"){   
                    map[key][0].animate({
                        'fill': '#000000',
                        'opacity' : 0.6
                    }, 500);
                }
            }


    }
btnstatus+=1;
}
```

It does shade / unshade every possible path (not only those sold or reserved) because parameter returns me undefined.
How should I do to get the desired STATUS in my loop? :)

I am a graphic designer with JS basics and I am aware that this may be as simple as alphabet. Yet - no experience, lack of knowledge - please help.
And sorry for any language mistakes ;)
Greets!

Comment: What svg JS library are you using?  It would be helpful if you created an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I tried my best. Sorry mate if it's unclear - I am not a pro :(
It is based on SnapSVG library http://snapsvg.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently the .data I was looking for was not saved into map[key] but in an inner array map[key][0] which contains SVG path. This is where all the .data is saved.

```
if(map[key][0].data('status')!=="free"){
```

was what I was looking for. Thanks to all who stepped by.